# Not all pictures appear in apps

Tags: iphone, photos, icloud

Ever since I enabled iCloud Photo Library, only my most recent photos have been appearing in apps. For example, if I go to upload a picture to Twitter, only the last 70 out of 300 pictures are shown. This holds true for other apps like Instagram and Dropbox, but the numbers do vary slightly (anywhere from 70 go 66 photos).

When I change my profile picture on Instagram, I have access to Momements, which includes all the photos, but not when uploading a picture to post.

Is there an issue with my iPhone, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that imported pictures aren't displayed in the "**Media Inspector**" > "**Photos**" tab > "**iCloud** "sidebar item…

In "**iPhoto.app**" > "**Preferences**" <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> check if in the "**iCloud**" tab the followings are ticked :

- "**My Photo Stream**"
- "**Automatic Import**"

[image: "iPhoto.app" > "iPhoto" menu > "Preferences" > "iCloud" tab]

If so you might consider creating a "**Smart Album**" <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>
For example "**iCloud Stream**" that will match "**all**" the following conditions :

[image: "iPhoto.app" > "File" menu > "New Smart Album …" item]

- "**Keyword**" > "**is**" > "**Photo Stream**" ;

*get last month (as for iCloud)*

- "**Date**" > "**is in the last**" > "**1**" > "**Months**" ;

[image: Creating a "Smart Album" with name "iCloud Stream" meeting "all" the following conditions date is in "the last 1 month" and keyword is "Photo Stream"]

In a "**Media Inspector**" you may know select your newly created smart album "**iCloud Stream**" :
[image: "Media Inspector" > "Photos" tab > "iCloud Stream" smart album]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that this was on an iPhone.

Comment: With iDevices : It seems the only way is to Share the pictures outside the Photo Stream, how ever I now see in my "Photos & Camera" setting "iCloud Photo Library (Beta)" which should radically solve your issue.

Comment: Right, but that's a feature I'd like to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have a number of apps that allow me to share photos. Some of them, like StacksExchange, start out with allowing me chose which album I want to upload from. Others, like Tumblr and Line default to the Camera Roll, but provide a dropdown menu, accessible by tapping the word Camera Roll. Dropbox allows me that same option:

[image]
[image]

I do not use Twitter; but I would suggest tapping on the word 'Camera Roll' and seeing if that allows you access to you album and Photo Stream.

Answer (score 0):

When you enabled iCloud Photo Library, you may have also selected or enabled "optimize Photos". What that does to your photos is stores them physically on the iCloud and not your phone. Sure you can view them in gallery but when you go to sharing them, it only shows the ones physically saved to the phone itself.